# What is this irregular-shaped bluish flower?

Tags: identification, flowers, wildflowers

What is this irregular-shaped bluish flower? ZONE 7. Half shade.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be Blueweed or Viper's Bugloss (*[Echium vulgare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echium_vulgare)*); a reliable weed for roadsides in hot dry summers, provides food for bees. Often seen in long dense patches by motorways.

Comment: What to do if I want more of these in my yard?

Comment: Give it open ground, hot sun, poor soil and don't mow that area.